# Não consigo mudar o valor de variaveis dentro de um loop

Tags: python-3.x, lógica

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte exercício:

> > Desenvolver um programa para verificar a nota do aluno em uma prova com 10 questões, o programa deve perguntar ao aluno a resposta de cada
> >     questão e ao final comparar com o gabarito da prova e assim calcular o
> >     total de acertos e a nota (atribuir 1 ponto por resposta certa). Após
> >     cada aluno utilizar o sistema deve ser feita uma pergunta se outro
> >     aluno vai utilizar o sistema. Após todos os alunos terem respondido
> >     informar:
>
> ```
> Maior e Menor Acerto;
> Total de Alunos que utilizaram o sistema;
> A Média das Notas da Turma.
>
> Gabarito da Prova:
>
> 01 - A
> 02 - B
> 03 - C
> 04 - D
> 05 - E
> 06 - E
> 07 - D
> 08 - C
> 09 - B
> 10 - A
> ```

Para isso pensei no seguinte algoritmo:

```
respostas =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'] #Lista com as respostas do teste


    #Declaração das variaveis
    maiorAcerto = 0
    menorAcerto = 10
    totalAlunos = 0
    media = 0

    while True:
        cont = 0
        acertos = 0
        erros = 0
        for resposta in respostas: #For loop que vai verificar se a resposta digitada é igual ao item correto da questão
            item = input('Digite a resposta da questão %d: '%(cont + 1)).lower()

            if resposta == item:
                acertos += 1

            else:
                erros += 1

            cont += 1

        totalAlunos += 1 #Incremento de aluno
        media += acertos #Acumuda o número de acertos em média

        if acertos > maiorAcerto: #Teste para saber se o aluno obteve a maior quantidade de acertos
            maiorAcerto = acertos

        if erros < menorAcerto: #Teste para saber se o aluno obteve a menor quantidade acertos
            menorAcerto = erros


        #Verifica se mais um aluno deseja checar suas respostas.
        continuar = input('Deseja continuar a usar o programa? Digite S(sim) ou N(não)\n').lower()

        if continuar == 's':
            continue

        elif continuar == 'n':
            break

    media = media / totalAlunos #Calcula a média dividindo o total dos acertos pelo número de alunos

    print('%d alunos usaram o sistema'%totalAlunos)
    print('A maior quantidade de acertos: %d'%maiorAcerto)
    print('A menor quantidade de acertos: %d'%menorAcerto)
    print('A média da turma foi: %.2f'%media)
```

Porém, ao finalizar o programa, a variavel maiorAcertos, menorAcertos e média estão com os valores iniciais. Eu preciso usar o global para modificar uma variavel dentro de um loop ou estou esquecendo algo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja, você definiu o array com as respostas da seguinte maneira

```
respostas =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

Na hora de validar o que o usuário digitou, você está fazendo

```
item = input('Digite a resposta da questão %d: '%(cont + 1)).lower()

if resposta == item:
```

Logo, você está comparando uma `string` maiúscula com um `string` minúscula, esse é o único problema do seu código. Esse `lower()` deve ser trocado por `upper()`.

Comment: Puts acabei esquecendo desse detalhe. Obrigado pela ajuda!